# How can I fix an APK file for Android. made with msfvenom too run on my new version of android

Tags: hackage

I tried run an APK file I created with msfvenom for a "android hack test", but after installing the application it was showing me this on my Android:::

MainActivity

This app was built for an older version of Android and may not work properly. Try checking for updates or contact the developer.

Please I need help on what too do ??

I tryed the $d2j-apk-sign, but still not working.. maybe I did not get the parameters rigth ‍♂️